# MVC Razor Html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

In Asp.net MVC 4, I want to make a html extend method.

I want it work like this:

in Razor View:

```
<button type='button' click='domethod'>click</button>
 @helper.minify(
    <script>
        function domethod() {
             alert('I'm script!');
        }
    </script>
 );
```

I think how can I make it render:

```
<button type='button' click='domethod'>click</button>
<script>function domethod() {alert('I'm script!');}</script>
```

May I create a extend in backcode, that it can recevie <script Tag> ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Extensions:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Test(this HtmlHelper html, string expression)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString("Data");
    }
}

@Html.Test("my test")
```